# Protractor locator can't find html element in phantomjs only

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, protractor

I have a few tests that are running fine in chrome, but if I switch to phantomjs, I have the following error:

```
Unable to find element with css selector '.selected-recipients a'
```

My test is simply this:

```
it('should navigate when clicking edit', function() {

    var editLink = element(by.css('.selected-recipients a')).element(by.css('.edit-preview'));

    editLink.click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('#/recipients');
});
```

This works fine on chrome. The problem is phantomjs. I found a post that suggests that the problem might have to do with window size, but that didn't solve the problem for me:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/585

I also tried to use by.id instead of by.css and I have the same problem. All other tests in this file work fine and some do use by.css, so it doesn't look like a problem with phantomjs understanding this locator. It seems like the element is not in the page at all.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When phantomjs is acting in a strange way I dump a screen shot.
Probably not what you are looking for, but it is an idea. :)

```
page.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com", function()
{
    page.render('script_ending.png');
}
```

Another idea is to try dumping the html to a file, to see if the element is there.

Or try changing the DOM, inserting an element, then see if you can find it.

Or try searching by just the class name, to see at what point it fails... maybe there is no child element of tag a.

Comment: Where does `page` come from? I think `browser.takeScreenshot` is the right way to take screenshots in protractor. You should put example code to dump the html to a file.